# Difference between Datastore and Core APIs when just storing files in Dropbox?

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I'm about to connect a browser-based JS app to Dropbox. I was about to settle with [dropbox-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js) when something caught my eye in the blog post [*Writing a file with the Dropbox JavaScript SDK*](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/71/writing-a-file-with-the-dropbox-javascript-sdk):

> As a side note, I'm using the Datastore SDK here. You could instead use dropbox.js from GitHub instead. The Datastore SDK includes the same file functionality.

This is weird. First of all, dropbox-js is the only project in the Github organization "Dropbox" that is marked "unofficial." The project isn't exactly beaming with activity (last release was 7 months ago, some of open issues have been opened by the original author 2 years ago).

The Datastore SDK, on the other hand, is [well documented](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/js) (but closed source?).

So, given that I want to just read/write files from Javascript, what SDK should I use and why? **Is there a difference between Datastore and Core API?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference is that the Datastore SDK includes "datastores" (a means of syncing structured data with automatic conflict resolution).

The file portion of the Datastore SDK should pretty much be identical to dropbox.js, since it's a fork.

Comment: Which one is the fork?

Comment: As I said, the Datastore SDK is a fork.